# Why does the SystemTray has a bottom border in WXGA simulator?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, system-tray, windows-phone-8-emulator

I wonder how I can remove the bottom border of the system tray in WindowsPhone8-App on WXGA resolution?

Here is what happens on WXGA simulator:
[image: the small gray line does not appear eg in 720p emulator]

the small gray line does not appear eg in 720p emulator

Comment: can you please explain what you are asking for ?

Comment: Oh indeed. And not just the emulator, it happens on the device as well. Weird.

Comment: @MohamedThaufeeq I just wanted to know how to remove that horizontal grey line! - See the answer below!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't really understand why it happens, but you can fix it by setting a negative top-margin on the root element of your page:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Gray" Margin="0 -1 0 0">
```

Comment: This does work (the Grid has to have a background color for sure).
However, the gray stroke will reappear on page navigation.. No clue how to fix this..

Comment: Works for my L1320 with 720p-resolution as well! Thx :)

Answer (score 8):

To fix this issue for the whole application (including on page transitinos) just add 1 line to the InitializePhoneApplication method in your **App.xaml.cs**

```
private void InitializePhoneApplication()
{
    //...

    RootFrame.Margin = new Thickness(0, -1, 0, 0);

    //...
}
```